# Is there a way to keep an android 6 phone connected to a wifi router that has no internet

Tags: android, wifi, connectivity

I'm making an app for a company that will be used in the internal network (WiFi) that does not have internet access, so with android 6 the phone connects and disconnect all the time in periods of least than 3 seconds.
Is there a way to disable that option?? unchecking the "avoid poor connection" on the wifi-advance menu doesnt help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be more on topic on superuser.com

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130265/stay-connected-to-specific-wifi-which-has-no-internet

Comment: I had already seen that stackexchange thread and tried the methods but none worked... not with an unrooted phone sadly